# Crear data.table y exportar a txt

Tags: r, datatables, rstudio

El objetivo final es crear un txt donde cada fila es distinta.
Para ello tengo distintas variables con distintos valores que se van a ir combinando. 
La solución que aporto no me parece la mas adecuado ya que si el numero de valores es mayor el código a escribir seria muy largo, quizás un `for`, la problemática que veo que la primera linea de la salida es distinta a las siguientes, y que se volvería a repetir para un nuevo valor de la variable personas.

**Código**

```
personas <- data.table(c("Luis","Pedro","Mar"))

año <- "2018"

mes <-"05"

dia <- "23"

dia2 <- data.table(c("lunes","martes","miercoles","jueves","Viernes"))

salida <-data.table(paste(año,mes,dia,personas[1],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[1],dia2[1],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[1],dia2[2],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[1],dia2[3],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[1],dia2[4],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[1],dia2[5],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[2],dia2[1],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[2],dia2[2],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[2],dia2[3],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[2],dia2[4],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[2],dia2[5],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[3],dia2[1],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[3],dia2[2],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[3],dia2[3],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[3],dia2[4],"&",sep=""),
                    paste(año,mes,dia,personas[3],dia2[5],"&",sep=""))

salida

salida2 <- t(salida)
```

**La salida que obtengo es:**

```
    [,1]                     
V1  "20180524Luis&"          
V2  "20180524Luislunes&"     
V3  "20180524Luismartes&"    
V4  "20180524Luismiercoles&" 
V5  "20180524Luisjueves&"    
V6  "20180524LuisViernes&"   
V7  "20180524Pedrolunes&"    
V8  "20180524Pedromartes&"   
V9  "20180524Pedromiercoles&"
V10 "20180524Pedrojueves&"   
V11 "20180524PedroViernes&"  
V12 "20180524Marlunes&"      
V13 "20180524Marmartes&"     
V14 "20180524Marmiercoles&"  
V15 "20180524Marjueves&"     
V16 "20180524MarViernes&"
```

Faltaría la exportación a `txt` donde quitaría los nombres de fila y de columna.

¿Alguien podria aportarme otra solucion mejor?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma bien sencilla usando código base es la siguiente:

```
# Para esta solución conviene que los valores sean vectores no data.tables
personas <- c("Luis","Pedro","Mar")
año <- "2018"
mes <-"05"
dia <- "23"
# Acá agregamos un blanco a la lista de días
dia2 <- c("lunes","martes","miercoles","jueves","Viernes", "")

cbind(do.call(paste0, expand.grid(paste0(año, mes, dia), personas, dia2, "&")))

     [,1]                     
 [1,] "20180523Luislunes&"     
 [2,] "20180523Pedrolunes&"    
 [3,] "20180523Marlunes&"      
 [4,] "20180523Luismartes&"    
 [5,] "20180523Pedromartes&"   
 [6,] "20180523Marmartes&"     
 [7,] "20180523Luismiercoles&" 
 [8,] "20180523Pedromiercoles&"
 [9,] "20180523Marmiercoles&"  
[10,] "20180523Luisjueves&"    
[11,] "20180523Pedrojueves&"   
[12,] "20180523Marjueves&"     
[13,] "20180523LuisViernes&"   
[14,] "20180523PedroViernes&"  
[15,] "20180523MarViernes&"    
[16,] "20180523Luis&"          
[17,] "20180523Pedro&"         
[18,] "20180523Mar&"
```

- Usamos [`expand.grid()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/expand.grid.html) que nos genera la combinación de todos los valores pasados como parámetros
- Luego con [`do.call()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html) ejecutamos un `paste0` de las columnas
- Por último, con  [`cbind()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cbind.html) convertimos todo en una matriz de una sola columna

Nota, si aún necesitas usar los `data.table` te recomiendo hacer un `unlist()`de los mismos antes de pasarlos como parámetro a [`expand.grid()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/expand.grid.html):

```
cbind(do.call(paste0, expand.grid(unlist(personas), paste0(año, mes, dia), unlist(dia2), "&")))
```

#### Si es importante el Orden

Para ordenar por Fecha, Persona y Día de la semana:

```
personas <- c("Luis","Pedro","Mar")
año <- "2018"
mes <-"05"
dia <- "23"
dia2 <- factor(c("", "lunes","martes","miercoles","jueves","Viernes"), ordered=T)

m <- expand.grid(paste0(año, mes, dia), as.character(personas), as.character(dia2), "&")
cbind(do.call(paste0, m[order(m$Var1,m$Var2,m$Var3),]))
```

Comment: Una cosa sobre la solucion. Faltaria una fila por persona, donde solo aparece la persona, haria falta una primera fila 20180523Luis, luego 20180523LuisLunes, 20180523LuisMartes...así hasta el viernes y  luego comenzar con Pedro, con 2018052Pedro la siguiente fila 20180523PedroLunes... y así

Comment: @Uko Te entiendo, simplemente habría que agregar un blanco a la lista de los días de semana, ahí edito la respuesta

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente con el blanco se arregla ese problema, lo unico q sigo sin saber como hacer que aparezcan seguidos los de Luis, luego todos los de Pedro y por último todos los de Mar, creo un data con cbind(do.call...) y los ordeno y si aparecen los de Pedro juntos pero no mantiene el orden de lunes, martes, miercoles... Alguna idea?

Comment: @Uko, revisa mi última edición

Comment: Perfecto!!! Así es como queria, muchas gracias!!!!